# centering content with -ms-content-zooming

Tags: zooming, image, center, winjs, winapp

I've been using this sample to create a "zoomable" content:
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Scrolling-panning-and-47d70d4c

My HTML:

```
<div id="zoomElement" class="zoomElement ManipulationContainer">
    <img id="zoomContent" class="zoomContent" alt="" src="sample.jpg" />
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
.zoomElement {
    overflow: auto;
    -ms-content-zooming: zoom;
    -ms-scroll-rails: none;
    -ms-content-zoom-limit-min: 20%;
    -ms-content-zoom-limit-max: 500%;
}
```

Now, no matter what, I've been unable to center the img in its container when it's unzoomed.

Comment: Can you give more details on what you tried?

Comment: I think the issue is not about div positioning, but about `-ms-content-zoom-limit-min: 20%;`. When it is below 100%,  the 'unzoomed' content will always be at top left of its ManipulationContainer.

Comment: note: we've dropped the related project 4 years ago